# Find a user in bunch of ArrayLists

Tags: java, android, oop, arraylist

Lets say i have the following classes:

```
Main->Worlds->Country->Cities->Streets->People->Person
```

And lets say that each class have his own `ArrayList`. 
If I only have access to the `World` class, To find a person by his name, Should i go the whole way from

```
getWorlds()->getCountries()->getCities()->getStreets()->getPeople()->getPersonByName('dani')
```

And like loop it, to search in all `instances`.
Or maybe it is a good practice to create like `ArrayList<Person>` in my `Main` class and have the persons both in this `ArrayList<Person>` and in the `People`'s  classes instances.
I hope that i was clear enough with my question. If it is not clear, comment me out.
Just to be clear, The problem is **NOT** to find a person by his name, it could be the family name, the ID, or anything else.

Comment: I would assume that `getPeople()` call returns a subset of all people. If you're only looking to find the person by name in that subset, that's how you should get it.

Comment: The problem is not to find a person by name. What i mean is that to use `getPeople()`, I will have to use about 7 loops. That is makes no sense. I need all the persons to be accesible easier.

Comment: i think it means each world contains a country which contains a city which contains a street which contains people which contain a person. Yeah... i think 7 loops is what you're going to have to do unless you implement some sort of database querying type structure.

Comment: Then maybe `Worlds` should have its own `getPeople()` method that is a superset of the others.

Comment: Yes, but it does not solve it. I tought about adding a `ArrayList<Person>` in the `Worlds` class and add the persons both to `People` and `World`

Comment: Should of created a structure where each person would have a Country City Street World all under his own name.. then you can just loop each person and check if they match all Street City World Country etc... in 1 loop

Comment: It is probably a good answer. But i must have this structure.
The post is just a concept. In my real application i have other Classes and I have to use it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it exactly like a database... by mapping this to other things.

for instance..

```
person array

       world
       city
       street
      country

world array
      countries

country array 
      cities

city array 
       streets

street array
      people
```

You can just have one main array with all the people in it.

everything else will have subsets of each other.

Comment: And if i want to remove a Person from the database. I will have to do it twice?

Comment: You'll have to write a little code for that but it would be minimal i believe. Get the street array remove the person from the street array first then update street array then remove person from main array.

Comment: There is a way for the people in street and the main array of people to be referenced. Just by passing the object into the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Create a hashmap in your main class (or better yet some kind of repository calss) that will map all the people by their names (add items to it when you create your "street" object, if applicable).
this way you can quickly get a person by name in all parts of the system.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but that was not the problem. I edited my post to be more clear.

Comment: you can have an arraylist on the main, of WeakReference objects to all your Person objects (instead of a reference to the real object). this way you can work with it, and items will be managed for you if you remove them from any other place.

Comment: That is probably what I was looking for. I will search for more data about it on google..